# Copying ISO files into a new directory after extraction

Tags: python, python-2.7, iso, shutil

I'm using `shutil` and [ISO9660](https://github.com/barneygale/iso9660/blob/master/iso9660.py) and trying to copy the extracted ISO files into a new directory. However when I attempt to copy the information I'm getting an error telling me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uboot.py", line 7, in <module>
    unzip_iso("dsl-4.11.rc1.iso")
  File "/home/baal/bin/python/uboot/lib/settings.py", line 138, in unzip_iso
    shutil.copyfile(iso_item, create_filename(filepath))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/BOOT'
```

The code I'm using:

```
def unzip_iso(filepath, verbose=False):
    iso_file = ISO9660(filepath)

    def create_dirname(path):
        data = path.split("/")[-1]
        items = data.split(".")
        return items[0]

    for iso_item in iso_file.tree():
        if iso_item == "/":
            pass
        else:
            shutil.copyfile(iso_item, create_dirname(filepath))
```

How can I successfully copy the ISO files over to a new directory?

Comment: what is 'filepath'? the directory doesn't exist; use `os.makedirs()` to make sure it exists first.

Comment: I created the directory, it still will not work though.

Comment: very likely you don't have write access to the root then... maybe try running the script with `sudo`?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I'll give that a shot thank you.